# How to make changes on maps from another activity to a blank fragment?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have created an blank activity and then a blank fragment into it and then I use to add google map to it when I add any button on blank activity. Then, How could I make changes on my map, if for example, I want to change type of my map then how it could be done?

**This is my main activity**

```
package com.example.maps;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MapFragment f;
    GoogleMap mv;
    Spinner maps;
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        f=new MapFragment();
        //f=findViewById(R.id.google_map);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f).commit();
        maps=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> a=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),R.array.spinner_item, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        maps.setAdapter(a);
        maps.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if(Objects.equals(maps.getSelectedItem().toString(), "Normal View")){
                    mv.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Fragment Activity**

```
package com.example.maps;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment smf=(SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);

        smf.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
                LatLng latLng=new LatLng(33.803,72.368);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(100));
                MarkerOptions mo=new MarkerOptions();
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                mo.position(latLng);
                mo.title("Home");
                googleMap.addMarker(mo);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);


            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

I expect to change types of maps from my main and it can done on fragment activity.